# Laravel how to populate select box from database

Tags: php, laravel, controller

i have a database table that store list of country,now am trying to get the list of country in a dropdown form,but is not working, maybe am missing something.this is my controller code

```
` public function details($id){
        //fetch post data
        //$post = Post::find($id);

        $country_options = Country::pluck('country', 'id');
        $country_options = DB::table('regions')->orderBy('country', 'asc')->pluck('country','id');

        //pass posts data to view and load list view
        return view('dashboard')->with('country_options',$country_options);

    }`
```

and the code that echo the dropdown in my form look like this ` '

```
@foreach($countries as $country)'+
               '<option value="{{ $country->id }}"> {{ $country->country }}</option>'+
               '@endforeach'+`
```

and my route looks like this

```
Route::get('/Business', 'BusinessController@details')->name('Business');
```

but i keep getting this error message

```
Undefined variable: countries (View: C:\xampp\htdocs
```

have made research but could not fine the solution.
any help would be appreciated with proper documentation/explanation.thanks

Comment: The first thing I noticed is that you use `$countries` in view, but in the controller, you are passing `country_options ` to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that your passing one variable name to your view and trying to read with another name. I made some quick example for you. Here my table is "Pais" ("Country" in portuguese), and use an clorure route for the callback function. (Lavarel 5.4)

**Route (web.php):**

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $countries = \App\Pais::all();
    return view('test_stackoverflow')->with(['countries' => $countries]);
});
```

**View (test_stachoverflow.blade.php):**

```
<select name="countries" id="countries">
  @foreach($countries as $country )
    <option value="{{ $country->id }}">{{ $country->name }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsVOj.png)

---

Another option, if you want to stay with the pluck method:

**Route (web.php):**

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
  /* $countries = \App\Pais::pluck('name','id'); */
  // or
  $countries = DB::table('pais')->pluck('name','id');
  return view('test_stackoverflow')->with(['countries' => $countries]);
});
```

**View (test_stachoverflow.blade.php):**

```
  <select name="countries" id="countries">
    @foreach($countries as $id => $country )
      <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $country }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
```

Both solutions have the same result in the generated HTML.

Hope this can help you!
Best regards.

Comment: I think your pluck wont work....did you try it already or just wrote the code in answer? Because pluck returns a collection now and not an array!

Comment: You're right, is not an array, is a Collection. But this works, I executed and tested before paste here.
Explanation: The Collection class implements IteratorAggregate interface, that has the method getIterator, called implicitly in foreach statements. 

Links:
Collection: https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html
IteratorAggregate: http://php.net/IteratorAggregate

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `country_options` from your controller not `countries`

Try this

```
@foreach($country_options as $country)
    <option value="{{ $country->id }}">
        {{ $country->country }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

first you dont need $id if you want to gell all categories

relace controller code with:

```
public function details(){
    $country_options = Country::All();
    return view('dashboard',compact('countries'));
}
```